# Inno-setup start menu entries not required

Tags: windows, inno-setup

I am building a setup file for my program using inno setup but don't want to add start menu entries. What keyword/settings are required in inno-setup to achieve this?

Comment: Don't take downvotes as a personaI offence. I recommend you to delete this comment as it might get flagged and tends to make the situation worse than it is.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed a few English issues with your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the entries in then `[Icons]` section where the `Name` attribute starts with `{group}`. Example:

```
Name: {group}\MyExe; Filename: {app}\Bin\MyExe.EXE; WorkingDir: {app}\Bin; IconFilename: {app}\Bin\MyExe.EXE; Comment: Starty MayExe; IconIndex: 0
```